# How can I append and save a list into another file in Discord Py?

Tags: python, list, discord.py

I'm basically making something that will take the users content then puts it in the list. I would like to store it in another file called 'problems' how would I do that? This is my code for the main Discord Bot

```
import discord
import random
import problems

TOKEN = "SECRET"

client = discord.Client()

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print("Bot is ready!")

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    username = str(message.author).split('#')[0]
    user_message = str(message.content)
    channel = str(message.channel.name)
    print(f"{username}: {user_message} ({channel})")

    if message.author == client.user:
        return
    if message.channel.name == 'test':
        if user_message.lower() == 'hello':
            await message.channel.send(f"Hello {username}!")
            return
        elif user_message.lower() == 'bye':
            await message.channel.send(f"Bye!")
            return
        elif message.content.startswith("!store"):
            a = message.content[6:]
            await message.channel.send("Stored!")
            problemlist = problems.problem.append(a)
            print(problemlist)
    if user_message.lower() == '!code':
        await message.channel.send()
client.run(TOKEN)
```

Here's the inside of my problems.py

```
problem = []
```

Basically an empty list
What I'm getting when it prints the `problemlist` is None

Also, I would like the list to persist after the bot has restarted.

Comment: Can you clarify whether you want the variable in the `problems.py` to persist (i.e, do you want that list to still be there when you stop and restart the bot?)

Comment: @HPringles Yes I would want to :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In python (and all other languages that I know of), when you import another python file, it loads it as code, so if your `problems.py` is as you've stated above, it executes `problems = []` every time the script starts, and once the script starts, that content is cleared from memory.

If you are doing something really simple, the best approach here would be write the variable to a file, using `pickle` or `json`. I've given an example of reading and writing below.

```py
import json

def read(filename):
    """Open the file, read it and parse the json"""
    try:
        with open(filename, 'r') as json_file:
            return json.loads(json_file.read())
    except FileNotFoundError:
        return {}

def write(filename, save_object):
    """Open the file, and write the object as json"""
    with open(filename, 'w') as json_file:
        json_file.write(json.dumps(save_object))

# Get the problems list if it exists.
problems = read('problems.json').get('problems', None) 
# If it doesn't create it.
if problems is None:
    problems = []
problems.append("problem")
write('problems.json', {'problems': problems})
```

This would mean the `problems.json` file would look something like this:

```json
{
    "problems": [ "1", "2", "3", "4"]
}
```

Comment: For some reason it says that `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/denzel/Desktop/Bot/Denzelbot/Discordd/code.py", line 15, in <module>
    problems = read('problems.json').get('problems', None) 
  File "/home/denzel/Desktop/Bot/Denzelbot/Discordd/code.py", line 7, in read
    with open(filename, 'r') as json_file:
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'problems.json' ` 
I already made a problems.json and put in an empty problems set there.

Comment: My apologies, I'll update my answer quickly. If the file hasn't been created yet, it won't be able to read from it.

Comment: No I already created one it still says the same thing

Comment: It's likely that you've created the file in a place the script isn't expecting, try updating your code to do a similar thing to mine above and that should fix it.

Comment: What do you mean by doing a similar thing to yours above? I've already isolated the json file and the py file into the same folder. Edit: I just copy and pasted your code

Comment: Have you copied the updated code, including the try/except statement?

Comment: Sorry I'm too dumb to notice you edited the code... Thanks It works now! Also would like to ask is there any use case to use pickle over json or vice versa?

Comment: It's mostly personal preference, pickle is obfuscated (not easily readable) when it's written into the file, but JSON can be easily seen and edited outside of the code. So that's why I use it. But as I said, just personal preference for the most part

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/237285/discussion-between-airismything-and-hpringles).

Comment: I see thanks! Last question haha, I don't quite understand what these last 2 lines do? `problems.append("problem")
write('problems.json', {'problems': problems})`